# Adding OpenSSL Support to an existing TCP client

Tags: c++, linux, openssl

### Environment

- c++
- Ubuntu 16.04 ( x64 )
- OpenSSL

### Use-case

Add SSL support to an Existing TCP Client implemented using C++ and async IOs ( poll )

### Problem at hand

- Per the OpenSSL documentation, SSL_read/SSL_write are to be used ( among other things )
- My code already reads the data from the socket and should support encrypted and un-encrypted connections at the same time.

Having the above said, is there any way to blindly feed OpenSSL with the payload
read from the socket rather than reading it using SSL_read? (what if eg. I am reading from a file and not from a socket) Can I encrypt RAW buffers using OpenSSL?

Comment: Punch "bio pairs" into your favorite search engine. Just be careful, a TCP connection has a read and a write state, an OpenSSL connection only has a single state. [Do not assume](http://marc.info/?l=openssl-users&m=124386218929227) that a read operation can't change the write state or vice-versa (like you do with TCP).